# Integrating json-server with a react app deployed using aws amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2, aws-amplify, json-server

I have developed a react app with mock backend developed using json-server and had successfully tested in my local using the npm start command and was working as expected. Then i moved onto deploying the app in aws using aws-amplify and the deployment was also success. One issue that i face now is , how to make the json-server up in the aws amplify, since my all backend calls are failing now as json-server is not up. PFB the steps that i tried to integrate json-server in aws-amplify
1.In the build settings of aws-amplify i tried giving the below commands to ensure that a json-server is installed before the build and provided the command to start the json-server after '&&' to ensure the json-sever is made up after the sequence of build

- npm install -g json-server
- npm run build && npx json-server --watch db.json --port 3001

Pls. let me know is there a way in which i can make the json-server up along with the aws-amplify so that my backend calls are success. If aws-amplify is not the right option which aws service should i use to make my backend working. Can i deploy a mock-service using json-server in aws ec2 and try to invoke that service from my UI.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to run multiple applications when you 'npm start', use `concurrently` npm package (for local machine testing only, not as solution to run on a remote host like AWS etc).

Then you can amend your package.json file to run multiple applications as below example;

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"react-scripts start\" \"npx json-server --watch data/db.json --port 8000\"",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate JSON server, then connect to it, you can do this with Heroku which offers free hosting for personal/development projects.

I have also done this for one of my previous projects on GH; https://github.com/rbhachu/the-mojo-blog